Using nth-child for inconsistent formatting?
What is the most economical way to write this code?
.colHeaders div:nth-child(2),
.colHeaders div:nth-child(3),
.colHeaders div:nth-child(4),
.colHeaders div:nth-child(11),
.colHeaders div:nth-child(12),
.colHeaders div:nth-child(14),
.colHeaders div:nth-child(15),
.colHeaders div:nth-child(16) {background: lightgrey;}


And why can I tell nth-child to skip children at the start, but not the end, of my parent element?
For example:
.colHeaders div:nth-child (2,3,4,11,12,14,15,16) {background: lightgrey;}
.colHeaders div:nth-child (2-4,11-12,14-16) {background: lightgrey;}
.colHeaders div:nth-child (n+2,4) {background: lightgrey;}
.colHeaders div:nth-child (n+11,12) {background: lightgrey;}
.colHeaders div:nth-child (n+14,16) {background: lightgrey;}


Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

So of the 16 elements you want 2/3/4 and the last 5, right?

2/3/4, 11/12, and the last 3.

From your statements, you want

2/3/4, 11/12, and the last 3.

You can "merge" selectors using :is() and target individual ranges with nth-child and nth-last-child.
For ranges you can state these like "nth-child(n+X):nth-child(-n+Y)" where X is the first to be selected and Y the last.
Like so:


.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 70px);
  gap: 0.25em;
}

.item {
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.item:is(:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+4),
/*2, 3 & 4 */

:nth-child(n+11):nth-child(-n+12),
/*11 & 12 */

:nth-last-child(-n + 3))
/* last 3 */

{
  background: lightgreen;
}
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
  <div class="item">Item 8</div>
  <div class="item">Item 9</div>
  <div class="item">Item 10</div>
  <div class="item">Item 11</div>
  <div class="item">Item 12</div>
  <div class="item">Item 13</div>
  <div class="item">Item 14</div>
  <div class="item">Item 15</div>
  <div class="item">Item 16</div>
</div>



Of course there are many ways to write this, I'm sure someone can come up with something better. Naturally, adding a class to those items and targeting that would be optimal...and quicker, probably.

Perfect. Thank you!

I think it's easier to use the negation in this case:


.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 70px);
  gap: 0.25em;
}

.item {
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.item:not(:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+10),:first-child,:nth-child(13)) {
  background: lightgreen;
}
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
  <div class="item">Item 8</div>
  <div class="item">Item 9</div>
  <div class="item">Item 10</div>
  <div class="item">Item 11</div>
  <div class="item">Item 12</div>
  <div class="item">Item 13</div>
  <div class="item">Item 14</div>
  <div class="item">Item 15</div>
  <div class="item">Item 16</div>
</div>




I don't disagree but I think mine is easier to read!☺

Great answer, and clever. However, there are 19 children total, making the answer above more efficient. Thank you!
